# Mailing script is mixing mail recipients

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a mailing script that is sending a large mailing.
In this mailing is a unsubscribe button witch fills in the mailaddress from the recipients.
But for some reason when a mails goes to recipients A the mailaddress from recipients B is filled in.

A snippet of my script:

```
<?php
//First get 500 mailaddressess to send the mail to
$sql = mysql_query( "select mail_id, customers_email_address from " . TABLE_NIEUWSBRIEVEN_MAILING_LIST . " where nieuwsbrief_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $nID ) . "' and send = 0 order by mail_id limit " . $aantal_verzenden ) or die ( mysql_error() ); 

while ( $mail = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) )
{        
    $sendmail = new PHPMailer();
    $sendmail->AddReplyTo( $data['afzender_email'], ucfirst( $data['afzender_naam'] ) );                
    $sendmail->AddAddress( $mail['customers_email_address'] );
    $sendmail->SetFrom( $data['afzender_email'], ucfirst( $data['afzender_naam'] ) );

    // This part is filling in the mailadress at the subscribe button.
    $layout = str_replace( '{EMAIL}', $mail['customers_email_address'], $layout );

    $mbEnc = mb_internal_encoding();
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    $sendmail->Subject    = str_replace( '€', mb_encode_mimeheader('€', 'UTF-8'), $data['nieuwsbrief_titel'] );
    mb_internal_encoding($mbEnc);

    $sendmail->AltBody = str_replace( '{ONLINE_WEERGAVE}', 'http://myssite.nl/p-' . $data['url'],  str_replace( '{AFZENDER_ID}', $data['afzenderid'], $data['alt_mail'] ) );
    $sendmail->MsgHTML($layout);

    if(!$sendmail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $sendmail->ErrorInfo . "\r\n";
      mysql_query( "insert into nieuwsbrief_zender_errors ( email, error ) values ( '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $mail['customers_email_address'] ) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $sendmail->ErrorInfo ) . "' )" );
      mysql_query( "update " . TABLE_NIEUWSBRIEVEN_MAILING_LIST . " set send = 2 where mail_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $mail['mail_id'] ) . "'"  ) or die ( mysql_error() ); 
    } else {
      echo "Bericht succesvol verzonden!";
      echo $mail['customers_email_address'] . "\r\n";
      mysql_query( "update " . TABLE_NIEUWSBRIEVEN_MAILING_LIST . " set send = 1 where mail_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $mail['mail_id'] ) . "'"  ) or die ( mysql_error() ); 
    }

    $sendmail->ClearAddresses();
    $sendmail->ClearAttachments();

}
?>
```

$layout is containing the mail template with variables.
The unsubscribe button has a {EMAIL} variable.
As you can see in the script the $mail['customers_email_address'] is used for the AddAddress and for the {EMAIL} variable.
So how is it possible that those values are different from each other?

Comment: What value will $layout have initially? I fear if you are playing with same $layout value in foreach or resetting it all time with default template?

Comment: Yes that was the problem, I have searched for it for days, I can't believe that I didn't saw it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you change the {EMAIL} with $mail['customers_email_address'] in  $layout and when the second time you call $layout you don't have {EMAIL}.
You should fill $layout2 = str_replace( '{EMAIL}', $mail['customers_email_address'], $layout ); 
and send $sendmail->MsgHTML($layout2);

Then the original $layout should stay the same

Comment: Yes that was the problem, I have searched for it for days, I can't believe that I didn't saw it myself.